# Does homeomorphism preserve second countabity?

Tags: general-topology

This seems obviously true and i proved it, but i couldn't find this in googls, so i'm asking this to make sure.

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces.

Let $H:X\rightarrow Y$ be a homeomorphism.

Is $Y$ second-countable if $X$ is second-countable?

Comment: Yes. And if you have proved it, you don't have to ask anymore.

Comment: @Michael Thank you. I asked this to make it sure 100%. Sorry if this interrupts you.

Comment: No problem. The last sentence was semi-tongue in cheek.

Comment: Homeomorphisms preserve all the *topological*  properties.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Unfortunately a topological property is defined to be a property of a space which is preserved under homeomorphism - you can't use that circular logic in a formal setting.

Comment: In my definition is a property dependent only of the topology (the family of open sets) of the space.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla That's a fairly meaningless definition.

Comment: You can define a property without explicit mention of open sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally,  second- countability is preserved under open quotient maps. The same holds for first-countability.